Spivak's proof of Fubini's theorem
On Spivak "Calculus on Manifolds" p59 he provides a proof of Fubini theorem but there is a party i don't fully understand. We have in the hypothesis that $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $B\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ are closet rectangles and that $f:A\times B\to\mathbb{R}$ and we define the function $g_x:B\to\mathbb{R}^n$ by $g_x(y)=f(x,y)$. Also we define the Lower and Upper integrals of $g_x$ $$\mathscr{L}(x)=\sup_{\mathcal{P}_B}L(g_x,\mathcal{P}_B)$$ and $$\mathscr{U}(x)=\inf_{\mathcal{P}_B}U(g_x,\mathcal{P}_B),$$ where the sup and inf are taken over all the partitions $\mathcal{P}_B$ of $B$. He first prove that we have the following inequalities; $$L(f,\mathcal{P})\leq L(\mathscr{L},\mathcal{P}_A)\leq U(\mathscr{L},\mathcal{P}_A)\leq U(f,\mathcal{P})$$ for an arbitrary partition $\mathcal{P}$ obtained from a partition $\mathcal{P}_A$ of $A$ and a partition $\mathcal{P}_B$ of $B$ (we just take the cartesian product of the rectangles on each one). Now this is the part of the proof that i dont get; he says that since we have $\sup L(f,\mathcal{P})=\inf U(f,\mathcal{P})$, we have by the above inequalities that $$\sup L(\mathscr{L},\mathcal{P}_A)= \inf U(\mathscr{L},\mathcal{P}_A).$$ This seems intuitive, but why is this the case? Where does this implication come from?

The hypothesis of the theorem is that $f$ is Riemann integrable over the  rectangle $A\times B \subset \mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^m$. By the Riemann Criterion for integrability we have that for any $\epsilon >0$ there is a partition $\mathcal{P}_\epsilon$ of $A\times B$ such that
$$\tag{1}U(f, \mathcal{P}_\epsilon )-L(f, \mathcal{P}_\epsilon )< \epsilon$$
Associated with the  partition $\mathcal{P}_\epsilon$ of $A \times B$, we have partitions $\mathcal{P}_{A,\epsilon}$ of $A$ and $\mathcal{P}_{B,\epsilon}$ of $B$ such that every subrectangle $R$ determined by  $\mathcal{P}_\epsilon$ is of the form $R = R_A \times R_B$ where $R_A$ is a subrectangle determined by $\mathcal{P}_{A,\epsilon}$ and $R_B$ is a subrectangle determined by $\mathcal{P}_{B,\epsilon}$.
It follows from the inequality proved by Spivak that
$$\tag{2}L(f,\mathcal{P}_\epsilon)\leq L(\mathscr{L},\mathcal{P}_{A,\epsilon})\leq U(\mathscr{L},\mathcal{P}_{A,\epsilon})\leq U(f,\mathcal{P}_\epsilon)$$
Hence, from (1) and (2) we have
$$U(\mathscr{L},\mathcal{P}_{A,\epsilon})-L(\mathscr{L},\mathcal{P}_{A,\epsilon})<\epsilon$$
Consequently, we have shown that for any $\epsilon >0$ there is a partition of $A$ for which the difference in upper and lower Darboux sums of $\mathscr{L}$ is less than $\epsilon$. By the Riemann Criterion, it follows that $\mathscr{L}$ is Riemann integrable and
$$\tag{3}\int_A \mathscr{L}(x) \, dx = \sup_{\mathcal{P}_A}L(\mathscr{L},\mathcal{P}_{A})= \inf_{\mathcal{P}_A}U(\mathscr{L},\mathcal{P}_{A})$$
It is then an obvious consequence of (1), (2), and (3) and the integrability of $f$ that
$$\int_{A\times B}f = \int_A \mathscr{L}(x) \, dx $$

Not that Spivak starts out by taking arbitrary partitions of $A$ and $B$ and proving the inequality for the induced partition $\mathcal{P}$ of $A\times B$.  He could have started by saying take an arbitrary partition $\mathcal{P}$ of $A \times B$ and ...

Also to apply the Riemann Criterion it is only necessary to produce a single partition for which the difference in upper and lower sums is less than $\epsilon$.

It follows by the simple logic of the supremum and infimum opererations applied to the terms of the triple inequality
$$L(f,\mathcal{P})\leq L(\mathscr{L},\mathcal{P}_A)\leq U(\mathscr{L},\mathcal{P}_A)\leq U(f,\mathcal{P}).\qquad(1\text{a,b,c})$$
Given that you accept these inequalities and also the author's statement that
$$\sup L(f,\mathcal{P})=\inf U(f,\mathcal{P}),\qquad(2)$$
we get from ineq. $1$a that $\sup L(f,\mathcal{P})\leq \sup L(\mathscr{L},\mathcal{P}_A)$, and ineq. $1$c gives $\inf U(\mathscr{L},\mathcal{P}_A)\leq \inf U(f,\mathcal{P}).$ Moreover $\sup  L(\mathscr{L},\mathcal{P}_A)\leq \inf U(\mathscr{L},\mathcal{P}_A)$; hence
$$\sup L(f,\mathcal{P})\leq \sup L(\mathscr{L},\mathcal{P}_A)\leq \inf U(\mathscr{L},\mathcal{P}_A)\leq \inf U(f,\mathcal{P}).\qquad(3\text{a,b,c})$$
Thus eqn $2$ squeezes the middle terms of ineq. $3$  together to equal the end points, and
$$ \sup L(\mathscr{L},\mathcal{P}_A)\leq \inf U(\mathscr{L},\mathcal{P}_A).$$
